# How to get Javascript to automatically play audio at a certain times of the day

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am building a wallboard system for a restaurant, and they would like to include an alarm that goes off at 3 different times throughout the day, every day, to remind the team to do certain tasks. I have most all of the wallboard built already using php and html, but I am having some trouble with the alarm system. From what research I have done, Javascript seams to be the language of choices to accomplish this, but when I built this simple system below, it didn't work. Javascript can find the audio file if you press the play button, and the timer will work after you have played the audio once, but when I try just running with the alarm aspect on it's own, it doesn't work. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have done a decent amount of research on this topic, and have tried several different methods to get this to work, and this seamed to me the only version that I could get to work... even a little.

Also, for the record, I am running the program on Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP, and am using Chrome/Chromium to view the webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="/include/sanitizer_reminder.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="/include/sanitizer_reminder.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p>This is a test</p>
<div id="timeid"></div>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
} 
</script>
<script>    
window.setInterval(function(){ // Set interval for checking
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
    var date = new Date(); // Create a Date object to find out what time it is
    if(date.getHours() === 10 && date.getMinutes() === 0 && x.paused){ // Check the time
        x.play();
        setTimeout(function() { x.pause(); }, 20000);
    }
    if(date.getHours() === 14 && date.getMinutes() === 0 && x.paused){ // Check the time
        x.play();
        setTimeout(function() { x.pause(); }, 20000);
    }
    if(date.getHours() === 18 && date.getMinutes() === 0 && x.paused){ // Check the time
        x.play();
        setTimeout(function() { x.pause(); }, 20000);
    }
}, 30000);
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
document.getElementById("timeid").innerHTML = time; 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The check for playing the audio checks x.paused.  Maybe that isn't set until you've manually played and paused?

Comment: I have tried it without, and got the same result unfortunately. Also, as far as I can tell chrome doesn't require user interaction to play audio, so I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever comes across this...

I ended up redesigning the system to use audio and video and took advantage of YouTube to render the video. I then used AJAX to check the page periodically to see if the time was set and if it was to trigger the video with the audio automatically.

The reason for this is because most browsers now require user interaction before allowing audio to play. This approach accomplished this in a way that is more user oriented, and honestly easier than what I was trying above. Plus the users enjoy it so it's a win win!

Hope this helps anyone out there, and if you have any questions please feel free to reach out!